# IComparable and Equals()

Tags: c#

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx)

> Types that implement  IComparable must override  Equals.Types that override Equals must also override GetHashCode; otherwise, Hashtable might not work correctly.

I didn't quite get it. Can anyone explain.

Comment: For more the relationship between Equals and GetHashCode: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overriden-in-c

Comment: Also note that while it is necessary that the contracts of IComparable, Equals, and GetHashCode() are adhered to in every case, it is not necessarily required to explicitly implement all three, so long as consistent results are achieved.  Primarily that means two objects with the same hash code are equal, and return 0 on CompareTo().

Comment: @rushinge I think the statement is wrong: 'Primarily that means two objects with the same hash code are equal, and return 0 on CompareTo().' . If the objects are Equal it is recommended that GetHashCode() to return the same value and CompareTo() to return 0. You can easily produce different/not equal instances that return same hash code :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IComparable is an interface that defines that two instances of the implementing class can be seen as greater than, less than or equal to one another. Since you have defined equality in the methods of that interface you also need to override the Equals method (and equality operator) to ensure the results from the two are consistent.

```
public class EqualityTest : IComparable<EqualityTest>
{
      public int Value { get; set; }

      public int CompareTo(EqualityTest other)
      {
           return this.Value.CompareTo(other.Value);
      }
}
```

In the above example I have implemented IComparable, but not overridden Equals. If you call CompareTo with two separate instances of the class that have the same Value it will say there are equal. If you call Equals with the same two instances it will say they are *not* equal as it will test to see if they are the same object (the default implementation of Equals).

Two equal items should return the same hash code (which are used for quickly finding items used as keys in hash tables) so if you override Equals then you should also override GetHashCode()

---

As an example I just created the following class in my IDE:

```
public class EqualityTest
{
     public string A { get; set; }
     public string B { get; set; }
}
```

And ran Resharper's helpful "Generate Equality" function saying that I wanted both A and B to affect equality. This is the code it created:

```
    public bool Equals(EqualityTest other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return Equals(other.A, A) && Equals(other.B, B);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (obj.GetType() != typeof(EqualityTest))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Equals((EqualityTest)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((A != null ? A.GetHashCode() : 0)*397) ^ (B != null ? B.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(EqualityTest left, EqualityTest right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EqualityTest left, EqualityTest right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
```

So if you are overriding Equals then you should also define all of the above to ensure consistency, if you are implementing IComparable then the same applies.

Comment: To my mind, if there exists a possibility that a type generally ahs a clear ranking order, but there may exist groups of values which are not equivalent to each other, but which have no natural ranking relative to each other, it would be entirely proper for `CompareTo()` to return zero but for `Equals()` to return false (e.g. I would posit that `Decimal` should behave that way when comparing `1.0m` and `1.00m`).  To my mind, `Equals` should define a relatively strict equality relation, even in cases where `==` or `CompareTo` might define a looser one.

Answer (score 1):

IComparable is used for comparing two objects - if these are considered equal then Compare will return 0. It would be very unexpected if IComparable.Compare returned zero for two objects, yet obj1.Equals(obj2) returned false since this would imply two different meanings of equality for the objects.

When a class overrides Equals, it should also override GetHashCode since two equal objects should hash to the same value, and this hash should be based on the fields/properties used in the implementation of equality.

Comment: If IComparable.Compare returns zero, does that really means the items should be regarded as equal, or merely that no clear ordered relationship exists?  Suppose one has an immutable class ScheduleEvent  which includes fields EventTime of type DateTime and EventAction of type MethodInvoker.  ScheduleEvent objects would have a natural ordering based on EventTime, but I would aver that ScheduleEvent objects with the same EventTime but different delegates should return 0 from CompareTo, but False from Equals.  That would seem cleaner than any other behavior.

Comment: `It would be very unexpected` Why? In many scenarios, value equality and object equality are different thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that objects in your code could be compared: `Equals` and `GetHashCode`

For your object to be compared properly in ALL situations, when you override the `Equals` method (used for some comparisons), you must also override `GetHashCode` (used in the rest).

If you override one but not the other, depending on your code, you could get unexpected results.