# how to compare two arrays of objects

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-3.5, comparison

i have an object called **Person**.  It has properties **First, Last, Age**, etc . . .

I have two arrays of Person objects.

I want to have some function to take two arrays

```
Person[] firstlist =  . .
Person[] secondList =  . .
```

and have it spit out two new arrays

```
Person[] peopleinFirstListandNotSecond
Person[] peopleinSecondListandNotFirst
```

Since these are not string arrays, i would want to do a compare on first and last name and age to determine if its the same person

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a linq function (`IEnumerable<T>.Except(...)`) that will do what you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx

Comment: You should probably add that he would need to compare the objects for equality, either by implementing a comparer, or doing the comparison within the lambda. Except on its own will not solve the problem.

Comment: The link is to the one with the `IEqualityComparer`.

Answer (score 7):

You could write a comparer (implement the [IEqualityComparer interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx)) then use it with the [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) extension method, as other posters have noted.

Or, you could just do the comparison within the lambda eg

```
var peopleinFirstListAndNotSecond =     
    firstList.
    Where( p => 
            !secondList.Any( s => 
                s.Age == p.Age && 
                s.FirstName == p.FirstName && 
                s.SecondName == p.SecondName
         ) 
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement IComparable (see [SO: IComparable and Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421289/icomparable-and-equals)) and then loop through each list, building the required two output lists.