# Implementation of IComparable not ordering

Tags: c#, linq, icomparable

I was getting the error "At least one object must implement IComparable" when trying to order data on the Thickness class, but I'm having difficulty in understanding how to implement ordering in this scenario with IComparable. Or, to be honest, what it even is. Here's my class with IComparable implemented, but not sorting. Any guidance would as always be appreciated.

```cs
public class ColourMatrix
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public class Item
    {
        public Colour Colours { get; set; }
        public List<Thickness> Thicknesses { get; set; }
    }

    public class Colour
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Thickness : IComparable<Thickness>
    {
        public int CompareTo(Thickness that)
        {
            return this.Measurement.CompareTo(that.Measurement);
        }

        public int Measurement { get; set; }
        public int StandardColour { get; set; } = 1;
    }
}
```

And I need to order the data like so.

```cs
var orderedItems = published.Items
    .OrderBy(n => n.Colours.Name)
    .ThenBy(t => t.Thicknesses.Select(x => x.Measurement));
```

In terms of output this is what it renders as, it's the 4, 2,1,3 that need to be ordered.

```
        | 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
red     | x |   |   |   |
green   | x |   | x | x |
blue    | x | x |   |   |
```

It should read

```
        | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
red     |   |   |   | x |
green   | x |   | x | x |
blue    |   | x |   | x |
```

Where x = the StandardColour property value

Comment: What does it mean to order by a list of measurements? If item 1 has thicknesses with measurements of { 1, 2, 3 } and item 2 has thicknesses with measurements of { 2, 3, 1}, which should come first, and why?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the reply. All measurements should come back in numerical order. For reasons I have no control of, the data is supplied to me as e.g. 4,3,1,2. 

In this case, 1,2,3,4 are the headings on the horizontal axis of a graph, so they need to be in order. Each colour has the same headings (but a different value in standard colour).

Comment: That doesn't really answer which item should be first though. Do you want to order by the maximum of the values? The minimum? Something else? What if one item has 10 thicknesses, and another just has 1? Or none? Basically, there's no "natural" comparison between two `IEnumerable<int>` values, so you'll need to specify your own comparison.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've updated with a visual that might explain myself better. All items will have the same values in.

Comment: you might need to implement equals and hashcode https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421289/icomparable-and-equals

Comment: @JochemVanHespen: No, there's no equality comparison here.

Comment: No, I'm afraid that doesn't help me. Note that your code isn't trying to reorder the thicknesses - it's trying to order the items by *considering* their thicknesses. I don't know what your red, green, blue example is trying to convey.

Comment: @JonSkeet Apologies, but thanks for bearing with me. 

So the example is saying the item red is available in size 4. Green in 4, 1 and 3 and blue is available in size 2 only.

In terms of display in the front end, it's confusing to the user to not have them display as 1 | 2 | 3 | 4.  So I'm trying to order them like so.

Comment: Okay, then what you're trying to do at the moment isn't where you want to be at all. Your `OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)` is *just* about ordering the items. It won't change the *thicknesses* at all. Adding an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're not trying to order the items - but change the content of the `Thicknesses` property so that all the thicknesses are *themselves* in order. You'd do that on each item separately. For example:

```cs
foreach (var item in published.Items)
{
    item.Thicknesses = item.Thicknesses.OrderBy(t => t.Measurement).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your help. I'd literally just gone down that route with mindset of "I've spent too long on this, I'll do it the messy way". The messy way being looping through each item and creating a new copy with the ordered thicknesses in. My code above eventually spits out Json, so can't be done on the frontend (easily). You helped me see where my mindset was wrong.